# Using navigation properties instead of foreign keys in Domain Driven Design and EF Core

Tags: entity-framework, domain-driven-design

I have domain entities, Product(parent) and ProductPart(child, Product, ProductId(shadow), Name). Their Id field setters are private.([because Ids are leaking abstraction](https://enterprisecraftsmanship.com/posts/link-to-an-aggregate-reference-or-id/)). (Using EF Core 2.1)

I am changing the name of ProductPart and the Product it belongs to (through ProductId foreign key).

If i should use Product navigation property ([linking entities](https://enterprisecraftsmanship.com/posts/link-to-an-aggregate-reference-or-id/)) instead of ProductId, then i have to load the whole Product from database which will be an overkill just for Id.

How could i use navigation property(Product) of ProductPart instead of ProductId foreign key with an optimal solution and without hacking Id(of Product) field by reflection?

```
public async Task<dbresult> GetOrCreateItemAsync(ProductPartViewModel itemViewModel)
{
    var productPart = await productPartRepository.GetOrCreateByIdAsync(itemViewModel.Id);

    productPart.SetName(itemViewModel.Name);
    // ProductId is Foreign Key
    productPart.SetProductId(itemViewModel.Product.Id);

    var dbResult = await productPartRepository.SaveChangesAsync();
    return dbResult;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

In Domain Driven Design, all entities are responsible of their own state. With navigation properties and public setters you violate that. You are also violating Law Of Demeter.

By being able to do `myEntity.OtherEntity.Name = "Arne"` you are bypassing all your services and all domain rules that are validated in them.

imho you shouldn't confuse view models with domain entities.

They have quite different purposes. The view models should have all their properties modifiable so that the UI can update them, while domain entities should have private setters and drive changes through methods to be able to protect their internal state (encapsulation).

Thus you are not really using DDD.

Comment: So you are right. I updated the code to look like more DDD. So I actually want to pass a fully fledged Product instead of a Product just with Id because fetching the whole Product from db just for Id seems suboptimal.